Integrated fridge freezer glitching and overheating
I've had a Beko BCFD150 integrated fridge/freezer for the last 5/6 years. Since buying it I've had the following issues intermittently:

Struggles to get cold (particularly in the fridge) even with thermostat turned to warmer temperatures. Verified with a fridge thermometer where I can see it is struggling to get below 8c even with the compressor running for long periods having been totally undisturbed for hours.
The compressor seems to be working too hard and is likely overheating. When this happens it makes a particularly loud/deep hum that is very noticeable and can get annoying. In fact it can stop me from getting to sleep even though it is almost on the opposite side of the flat to my bedroom. When it shuts off it can make quite a loud thump and the whole thing shudders harshly
Ice tends to be concentrated at the very top of the back of the fridge rather than all the way down
When it has been sat undisturbed for a while, walking up to it can sometimes cause it to toggle between running/not running. I thought it was just a coincidence the first few times but it happens so often that I am assuming the slight vibration is somehow enough to trigger something
Makes a very odd moaning noise which seems to be loudest in the fridge. I do have a recording and will see if I can post it on YouTube or something.

The strange thing is that sometimes if I switch it off for a while then back on again it starts to run perfectly fine for days and pretty much all of the listed issues temporarily disappear - it even sounds a lot quieter to the point where I barely notice when it’s running.
But it’s not a 100% reliable method and at any rate it always goes back to how it was before at some point, generally after 1-2 weeks or so. Around the time it starts playing up again I can often hear it running long defrost cycles as it makes no noise for extended periods other than occasional relay clicks but is drawing power. Then the symptoms gradually reappear
I would say the problems have maybe gotten slightly worse over the years I've had it but not really a huge difference
It has had a few people look at it but none has really done much investigation and each implied it would be better just to buy a new one. In fact it was due to be replaced under warranty at one point but due to a bereavement I had to cancel the appointment.
The issue where it's sensitive to vibration makes me think there could be a cracked PCB or other kind of bad connection but I don't know if it could be linked to the other problems
As it's an integrated unit it is going to be a huge pain to replace with a different model, especially as it's hard-wired in and installers here often aren't qualified to even deal with that. I'm just hoping someone might have seen something similar and know if it can sensibly be fixed or at least give me some way to test for possible causes of these problems.
Update:
Another repair man had a look and suggested it could just be lack of ventilation at the bottom, as there was only a small gap cut out from the plinth at floor level.
So we tested with the plinth removed and it did seem to help although the performance still seemed a little erratic at times. I bought a new metal grille approx 50cmx8cm and this was added to the plinth before it was replaced but almost immediately the unit started to overheat again and the vibration from the compressor returned. After switching it off for an hour and removing the bottom plinth completely it's running perfectly fine again but I don't know for how long and clearly it's not a solution. I've attached images showing the gaps for ventilation
A few people I asked me to check was the door seals but these seem fine, the doors close fully and seem to be making a good seal.
Images showing ventilation
Old vent in bottom plinth

New vent in bottom plinth

Top ventilation

Thanks in advance

You've had engineers look at it? Either you have friends in high places or you really like this appliance. Intermittent failure of this magnitude is usually evidence of impending total failure. It doesn't sound like a simple issue to me, but degradation of a major mechanical component. Control board faults don't usually cause groaning. I'm with the others (even as an environmentalist)--dump it.

I already mentioned it has been like this for 5/6 years, so an impending total failure is long overdue. And I'm not sure what else to call someone who comes out to repair domestic appliances when they often refer to themselves as engineers

I'd go with "technician". Engineers design the units. My point is that it's going to stop working completely at some point, possibly while you're away for the weekend with a load of expensive food at stake. Good luck.

You are probably right about the terminology thing although here in the UK I think we are a bit more lax about it. But I ideally wanted to get it sorted before I put my flat on the market to prevent possible future hassle and I really don't want to shell out a big sum of money for a new one

As for noise, most refrigerators come with a statement that they do make noise and are not suitable for use in a room used for sleeping. General Electric has recorded these sounds of normal operation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v2MbvX3fX0 . A thermoelectric fridge can be silent (or with just fan noise) -- but such devices are very inefficient, suitable only for chilling a can or two, or keeping medications cool.

"In fact it can stop me from getting to sleep even though it is almost on the opposite side of the flat to my bedroom". I don't understand how people can just downvote and not bother to even read

In North America, fridges with freezers are the most common, but some people also have an extra chest freezer to increase size/amount of use.  Thermostat should be turned to colder for cold temps, less than 40F/5C in the fridge, but just above 32F/0C.

I think the odds are low for a DIY solution, but a detailed log of the conditions and symptoms could help.  For example, "at 0800 on 09-05-24, the unit was silent.  I opened the fridge for 30 seconds.  When I shut the door, the groaning began and lasted 15 minutes."  For every opening of either unit, you would note the internal temp, initial condition, what you did, and what changed.  In addition, log the time periods you were present, the ext temp, and the nature, times, and durations of any sounds it made whenever you were present, and if you were aware of any other stimulus at onset or end.

Is there any way you can increase the ventilation around it for a day or two to see if that improves matters?

How old is it?  You've had it for 5/6 years.  Was it brand new at the beginning of that?  Or is it a 10+ year old unit that you met 5-6 years ago?  When you say integrated, do you mean that it is integrated into the cabinetry?  Or something else?  What is integrated about it?

@mdfst13: it was new when I bought it. Integrated means that it’s integrated into a wooden unit with doors that matches the rest of the kitchen, as opposed to being a freestanding item - this is common in the UK and also applies to dishwashers etc.

@Andrew Morton: To be honest I’m not sure how much ventilation there is around it as it is integrated into a wooden unit and I can’t see behind, but there is a vent at the bottom

In many ways, the easiest thing would be to replace it and make sure the next installers know what they're doing.  If you don't want to do that, there are some things you can do on a DIY basis:

Check the door seal, as suggested by MadMonty in this answer.  This seems quite possible, as the door is one of the things that is non-standard when you integrate the refrigerator with the cabinetry.  The installers could have done any number of things that might impact it.
Pull the refrigerator out of the space and look behind it.  It's not enough to just have a vent below the refrigerator (and is that truly below or part of the refrigerator).  There should be a vent at the top (not necessarily visible from below) to let air vent out.  There's also supposed to be a certain amount of space on each side to make it easier for air to circulate.

My personal guess would be venting.  That's something that is going to require extra effort to get right when the refrigerator is integrated into the cabinetry.  If your refrigerator was installed by cabinet installers rather than appliance installers, it is quite possible that they did not pay sufficient attention to venting and instead closed off all the places where air should travel (except the one vent).  Again, one vent is insufficient.  You want at least two.  One to allow air into the space and one to allow it out.  Because refrigerators exhaust heat (they pull heat out of the inside and put it outside), the vent in may be better low and the vent out high to take advantage of passive air flow.
While you have the refrigerator pulled out, see if it is able to defrost/fix itself.  If it is, that would lend further credence to venting being the problem.  You also might check if it is hot in the space behind the refrigerator when you first pull it out.
Venting is also something that would have been wrong from the beginning and not gotten worse over time.  Unlike a mechanical failure or a bad door seal.  Pull it out and see what happens.  If that helps, take pictures and post a new question.  People can help you improve the venting of the existing system.  If you have trouble pulling it out, pictures might also help people make suggestions as to how to accomplish that.

Thank you for your answer and sorry it took me so long to come back. Please see updated question

Replaced it with a newer model and it is much, much quieter in comparison

Although it would be hard to assign a single cause to the range of symptoms with certainty, the most likely problem is ice build-up beyond what the defrost cycle is able to remove.  Heavy ice build-up, contrary perhaps to intuition, reduces cooling efficiency.  This causes the compressor to run longer and harder, accounting for the ever louder groaning sounds.
To restore normal operation, one must typically either defrost the unit manually or shut it off long enough to melt the ice enough that it sloughs off the chilling plate.  This restores the normal efficiency.
The leading cause of excessive frost build-up is a poor door seal.  Clean both surfaces well and look for any deformities.  You can check for thin gaps by sliding a stiff bit of paper around the perimeter.  Order a replacement if needed.  And, of course, you want the door to close completely every time.  Objects inside that stick out will interfere.  The unit should be leveled (with shims if the built-in adjusters in the feet will not suffice) so that the door is inclined to close on its own if the door is inadvertently left ajar.
If these steps fail to remedy the problem, it may be because the defrost cycle does not run often enough.  You might consult the owner's manual or customer support service to see if this can be adjusted. Or you can commit to manually defrosting from time to time.  Otherwise, you would need a technician to repair it... if they can.
